# setting datetime to null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, date-range

I have two DateTime variables first period and second period and with each period i have a date range between two date for each period. My issue is that i usually set my dates to null withn i load the page but for these dates i cannot set them to null which i would like rather than setting a specific date.

```
DateTime firstPeriodBeginDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3);
DateTime secondPeriodBeginDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-2);
```

I would like it set to null so that it will equal to the values selected from the date picker by the user when used to render results.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`DateTime` is a non-nullable value type, so cannot be null.

You can use a [`Nullable<DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) for such a thing:

```
DateTime? firstPeriodBeginDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3);
DateTime? secondPeriodBeginDate = null;
```

Comment: It's probably worth editing the first part to "`DateTime` is a non-nullable value type, so cannot be null." After all, `Nullable<DateTime>` is a value type, too...

Comment: I tried this but my issue in my repository and services i am using a daterange and i am not sure of how to set that to null. I tried setting my date times to null but then i get errors when i build saying i cannot convert date range to null.

Comment: @Amina - Well, how can there be a range between dates if one of the dates is `null`?

Comment: first date = 01/20/2010 - 02/20/2010
second date = 02/20/2010 - 03/20/2010

for each of the dates i have a date range which could be a week, month, quarterly, or yearly and then i use a date time.

Comment: Get(DateRange firstPeriodDateRange, DateRange secondPeriodDateRange, int? officeId)
        {
            return DataContext.Report_ResultsData(firstPeriodDateRange.DateStart, firstPeriodDateRange.DateEnd,
                                                        secondPeriodDateRange.DateStart, secondPeriodDateRange.DateEnd,
                                                        officeId).AsQueryable();
        }

Comment: @Amina - I don't understand. Perhaps post a new question, referencing this one.

Comment: To go along with this: DateTime is a struct(value), so it can't be null. You have to box the struct into an object, which adds overhead any time you access it, but it'll do your job of being null. Another way is to have a default value that one can treat as null, like DateTime.Min, since one would have to check for null before comparing anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The `DateTime` structure cant be null.

But you can use a nullable `DateTime`

```
DateTime? dateTime;
dateTime = null;
```

and check for null

```
if (dateTime.HasValue)
```

More information: [C# Nullable DateTime](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-datetime)

hope this helps

Comment: when setting to DateTime.MinDate does that defult to the min value and pass it as a value to render results? I mean if my min value would be 1/1/0001 and it will render results based on that date and then will it change to whatever i choose from the date picker? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, not really clear what you mean. Could you explain it please. thank you